# Bad Method Call Exception

Tags: exception, model, laravel-5

Here is my route

`Route::get('desktops/{desktop}','DesktopsController@getdesktop');`

Here is my controller method

```
public function getdesktop($identifier)
{
    $desktop = Desktop::all()->where('identifier',$identifier);
    $casings = $desktop->casings();
    dd($casings);

}
```

I have added the App\Desktop, here is my casings method defined inside Desktop Class/Model

```
public function casings()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Casing');
}
```

Now it seems to be working on tinker, but when I open it in my browser it throws an exception of method not found or to be exact BadMethodCallException, even though I have method defined inside the class. I can't seem to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using this

```
desktop = Desktop::all()->where('identifier',$identifier);
```

which was returning a record set, with multiple records. Even though there was only 1 record, it was treating it as a collection. So I tried changing

```
desktop = Desktop::all()->where('identifier',$identifier)->first();
```

which only fetched me a single record and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you define the relationship in your model it is carried in to the eloquent object as a property rather than a function inside the collection.

As such you need to access it without the `()`:

`$casings = $desktop->casings;`

You can find out more about accessing the relationships in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: I tried doing that but that didn't work, so I tried something on my own and it worked just fine.